# Liferay : Customizing the persistence layer

Tags: java, liferay

I want to create my own persistence class in Liferay 6.1.1 that extends the XXXPersistenceImpl.

I have read [here](https://www.liferay.com/fr/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2023550) that it is possible

> You can just create a new PersistenceImpl class, let's say, XXXPersistenceImplChild, extending XXXPersistenceImpl class. After that, in your service.xml, you can edit the persistence-class attribute ;

My question is :

1. Is this the right way to do it in Liferay 6.1.1?
2. Is it a good practice to do so?

Comment: do you want to do this "just because you can" or is there an actual usecase?

Comment: There is an actual usecase. To solve a specific problem, I have come to multiple solutions including this one. I have read the documentation but it states that business logic must be implemented in the LocalServiceImpl therefore I would like to know if customizing the persistence layer is a good practice.

Comment: is it a good practice? depends on the usecase.